# Use of custom filter using office js to apply text filter on excel sheet table column

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I need to apply a filter to an Excel table using Office.js. I am able to apply the filter based on column value as follows:

```
function filterOutputSheet() {
    Excel.run(function (context) {
        var sheet = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");
        var outputTable = sheet.tables.getItem("OutputTable");
        var filter = outputTable.columns.getItem('column1').filter;          
        filter.applyValuesFilter(["test"]);
        return context.sync(console.log("filter"));

    })
};
```

But my requirement is to implement text filter contains in a column. I have checked the [docs in GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/reference/excel/filtercriteria.md). It has few properties like custom and criterion1 to implement a filter. But there is no sample code present.
Can I get some sample code to implement text filter with contains parameter.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

I was able to do something like this in Office.js:

```
filter.applyCustomFilter("*" + mySearchTerm + "*");
```

to implement a filter that returned rows containing my search term even though they weren't exact matches like the default behavior of `Excel.FilterOn.values`.

---

### Context

In Excel, go here on a column you want to filter:

[image]

This will open the Custom AutoFilter window. The fields in that window look similar to this little bit of documentation for applyCustomFilter():

[image]

My guess is they line up something like this:

[image]